# Growing directory of sequence files as a streaming input to Apache Flink

Tags: stream, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a directory of hadoop sequence files, where more sequence files are added intermittently. I want the source of Apache Flink Job for the streaming API to be this growing directory of sequence files. Is there a way in Apache Flink to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this API for streaming in `StreamExecutionEnvironment`:

```
readFile(FileInputFormat<OUT> inputFormat,
         String filePath,
         FileProcessingMode watchType,
         long interval)
```

But I have not found the predefined `InputFormat` for hadoop sequence file. Probably you have to provide one.